# How to create a "confirm" button in a modal with a redirect path

Tags: angular, typescript

I created a modal, when the user clicks on `confirm`, I would like the user to be redirected to the page =>  `securities-in-portfolio`.

[modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eLmXJ.png)

```
<div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
     <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="confirm()">
          Confirm
     </button>
</div>
```

Do you know how to write this in TS, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. in your component file.
You have to have a method named confirm. it looks like:

```
constructor(private readonly router: Router // -> add this) {}

confirm() {
   this.router.navigateByUrl('/ROUTE_TO_SECURITIES_IN_PORTFOLIO'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try routerlink

Instead of

```
(click)="confirm()"
```

Use

```
[routerLink]="['/securities-in-portfolio']"
```